# How to get dimensions of a multidimensional vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, stl, multidimensional-array

all

I am using multidimensional STL vector to store my data in C++. What I have is a 3D vector

```
 vector<vector<vector<double>>> vec;
```

What I want to retrieve from it is :

```
 &vec[][1][];    // I need a pointer that points to a 2D matrix located at column 1 in vec
```

Anyone has any idea to do so? I would be extremly appreciate any help!

Regards

Long

Comment: Why will you need this pointer?... If you want to iterate over this matrix you could do it with `vec[i][1][j]`...

Comment: The key question is: What are you trying to do? Please give us more context.

Comment: Hi, @Manu343726 What I want to do is to return a large-scale matrix from a function. Since my project has high requirements at speed performance. I have to return pointer instead of copies.

Comment: Hi, @Kyle_the_hacker What I want to do is to return a large-scale matrix from a function. Since my project has high requirements at speed performance. I have to return pointer instead of copies.

Comment: Is your matrix a square matrix?

Comment: have you access to C++11? Move-semantics provides by-value return without performance cost

Comment: You want to return part of the matrix represented by the three-dimensional vector, right? But is that return by reference or by value? That is, the user is allowed to modify the returned submatrix or not?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to consider `vec` just as a vector whose elements happen to be 
vectors-of-vectors-of-double, rather than as a multi-dimensional structure.

You probably know, but *just* in case you don't I'll mention it,
that this datatype does not necessarily represent a *rectangular cuboid*. 
`vec` will only have that "shape" if *you* ensure that all the vectors are
the same size at each level. The datatype is quite happy for the vector `vec[j]`
to be a different size from the one at `vec[k]` and likewise for `vec[j][n]` 
to be a vector of different size from `vec[j][m]`, so that your structure is "jagged".

So you want to get a pointer to the `vector<vector<double>>` that is at
index 1 in `vec`. You can do that by:

```
vector<vector<double>> * pmatrix = &vec[1];
```

However this pointer will be an unnecessarily awkward means of accessing that 
`vector<vector<double>>`. You certainly won't be able to write the
like of:

```
double d = pmatrix[j][k];
```

and expect to get a `double` at coordinates (j,k) in the "matrix addressed
by a `pmatrix`". Because `pmatrix` is a pointer-to-a-vector-of-vector-of-double;
so what `pmatrix[j]` refers to is the *vector-of-vector-of-double* (not vector-of-double)
at index `j` from `pmatrix`, where the index goes in steps of 
`sizeof(vector<vector<double>>)`. The statement will reference who-knows-what 
memory and very likely crash your program.

Instead, you must write the like of:

```
double d = (*pmatrix)[j][k];
```

where `(*pmatrix)` gives you *the vector-of-vector-of-double addressed by* `pmatrix`,
or equivalently but more confusingly:

```
double d = pmatrix[0][j][k];
```

Much simpler - and therefore, the natural C++ way - is to take a *reference*,
rather than pointer, to the `vector<vector<double>>` at index 1 in `vec`. You 
do that simply by:

```
vector<vector<double>> & matrix = vec[1];
```

Now `matrix` is simply *another name* for *the `vector<vector<double>>` at index 1 in `vec`*,
and you can handle it matrix-wise just as you'd expect (always assuming
you have made sure it *is* a matrix, and not a jagged array).

Another thing to consider was raised in a comment by manu343726. Do you
want the code that receives this reference to `vec[1]` to be able to
use it to modify the contents of `vec[1]` - which would include changing its
size or the size of any of the `vector<double>`s within it?

If you allow modification, that's fine. If you don't then you want to get
a *const reference*. You can do that by:

```
vector<vector<double> > const & matrix = vec[1];
```

Possibly, you want the receiving code to be able to modify the `double`s
but not the sizes of the vectors that contain them? In that case, `std::vector` 
is the wrong container type for your application. If that's your position I
can update this answer to offer alternative containers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using matrix from some linear algebra library. There are some directions [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library%20here)